# How does this bit of code work?

Tags: php

I'm going through Head First PHP and I've found this snippet of code in PHP.

It's supposed to display each row of records from a table containing the first_name, last_name and email.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] .
    ' : ' . $row['email'] . '<br />';
}
```

The `$row` array contains the next row obtained by `mysqli_fetch_array()`. But how is this a condition to be checked by the while loop? What exactly does the while loop evaluate to be true/false, before running the inner code? And why exactly does the loop stop when the rows have exhausted? There isn't even a condition to check for an EOF!. So how exactly does this work?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php . Go forth and learn.

Comment: @aynber **None** of those resources explain how the availability of data is interpreted as _True_ while a Null is interpreted as _False_. That's what I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [PHP Documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), mysqli_fetch_array() "Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset." So, when there are no more results, it returns null which evaluates to false and ends the loop.

Comment: So can we safely say that any text/content will always evaluate to "true" while anything containing NULL value will always evaluate to "false"..? or is this a special case?

Comment: my_sqli_fetch_array() returns an array of strings. Non empty arrays evaluate to true. NULL always evaluates to false. Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php to see which values evaluate to true/false for different types.

Comment: Thank you, that's the link that I needed.